# Resize navbar om resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need my navbar and the navbar items to change height on small screens.
So I created a @media rule, but I must be doing something wrong cause it doesnt work :/

> ```
> @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
> .navbar {
>     min-height: 20px;
> }
>
> .navbar-brand, navbar-nav li > a {
>     line-height: 20px;
>     height: 20px;
>     padding-top: 0px;
> }
>
> .navbar-brand {
>     padding: 8px !important;
> }
>
> .navbar-toggle {
>     margin-right: 18px;
> } }
> ```

Any answers will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: 1) Are you actually using **[LESS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/less/variables.less)** 2) This rule `navbar-nav li > a` needs to be (with a **DOT**) `.navbar-nav li > a` and 3) If you want this to take place only on smaller screens use **max-width**, not **min-width**. Please provide a minimal working example that displays the problem.

Comment: Im using ccs, so I was wondering if its allowed to use the @screen-sm-min ? or is this LESS functionality??

Comment: No it wont work with CSS. You need to use the actual value.